# Where can I get the source and header files for the gnu.org Simple Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu

Where can I get the source and header files for the [gnu.org "Simple Makefile" example](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Simple-Makefile.html#Simple-Makefile)?

I reallywant to experiment with this very good example, except the fact that I can't find the referenced source & header files.

Any pointers?

Comment: These can be any files named accordingly.

Comment: I doubt they exist (or ever existed). They aren't material (in content) to the makefile itself. Create any (even empty) files there and it will still "work" from a makefile perspective.

Comment: Of course they can. HOWEVER, that doesn't illustrate what the content of the files should be and how they reference one another.

Comment: For the makefile illustration it really doesn't matter. They can be even blank.

Comment: @EugeneSh. True, maybe OP is just expecting  the exact dependency mentioned in that tutorial. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh I understand that. But the doc authors intention is different.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ha ha, that is something I mentioned in my answer _long ago_. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your perspective, Eugene. However, I don't want to limit my question to be only "for the makefile illustration".

Comment: I wonder why people are coming here, asking a question, getting the answer, and then starting arguing about the answer correctness? If you know better, why asking? @Loveandpeace-JoeCodeswell If you look through the comments AND the answers, you will notice, that they ALL telling you the same thing.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's ok, don't take it personally, we know how to handle things now, don't we? Maybe a little more clarification and everything will be ok. Keep cool, it's just Monday, long week ahead :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about coding or software development.

Answer (score 1):

To create minimal files with which the sample  [Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Simple-Makefile.html#Simple-Makefile) will work, you can run:

```
touch {kbd,command,display,insert,search,files,utils}.c \
      {defs,command,buffer}.h;\
      echo 'int main(){}' > main.c
```

---

## Explanation:

The minimum C file that will compile into an object file is the empty file. For linking to succeed, you need one and exactly one main function.
The above code just creates empty `.c` and `.h` files mentioned in the sample Makefile and the `main.c` file with the main function.

As has been said, the contents don't matter so you might as well make it the minimum that works.

### The C build system and the interaction of `.c` and `.h` files

In a real-case scenario, the role of `.h` files is just that they get `#include`d from `.c` files. `#inclusion` is a literal copy and paste—you might as well replace each `#include` directive with the exact contents of what's getting included because that's exactly what the compiler will do.

The files that depend on `.h` files (according to the directives in the `Makefile`) should normally correspondingly `#include` the same header files.

#### Header-file dependency deduplication

Real-world `Makefiles` normally don't duplicate this info, but instead create header dependency files out out `.c` files (based on the `#include` directives contained within them) with something like (the header dependency files usually have the `.d` suffix):

```
#A makefile rule with some dynamic variables (more advanced make)
%.d: %.c
    $(C) $(CFLAGS) -MM -MF $@ -MT $*.o $<

#include will remake the dependency files if they need to be
-include $(CLIENT_SRC_C_D)
```

([tup](https://gittup.org/tup/), which is a great `Make` alternative does this automatically and language-agnostically based on filesystem reads).

Answer (score 0):

Does the *exact* content of the files REALLY matter here? I believe the purpose of the [linked manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Simple-Makefile.html#Simple-Makefile) is to describe the workings of the `make`, to show the syntax and semantics of writing and using a makefile, not for building any particular *real* application. The names used are just a notion. You can simply create the files with that particular name, if you want, and put some dummy functions.

For your reference, you can check [this alternative link](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/) which has the source codes for the used files, too. This is very simple example but should be enough to give you the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your perspective, Sourav. You MAY be correct that, "the purpose of the linked manual is to describe the workings of the make, to show the syntax and semantics of writing and using a makefile, not for building any particular real application". However my question was asked to hopefully broaden my understanding of the C build system against the backdrop of the "linked manual", particularly regarding the interaction among .c, & .h files.

Comment: @Loveandpeace-JoeCodeswell You're welcome Sir. Did you check the other link I provided in my answer? I thought that will be helpful. Meanwhile, Let me clear any doubt, I don't have any information regarding the existence of the actual files mentioned in the gnu tutorial. Nevertheless, I'll try to search one more time. :-)

Comment: Thanks, Sourav. I did. I still have a bit of a question generated, fortunately or unfortunately :) depending on one's point of view, from the Simple Makefile example. If I am the sole author of the edit program, what would be my motivation for having multiple .h files? Thanks again, Sourav.